# When is the dm_db_partition_stats updated?

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, scalar

I want to create a scalar SQL function that checks the row count of a table using dm_db_partition_stats. I have a handful of tables that get pushed to me and during that time the tools that use those tables are rendered useless.

I have these tables backed up on another server. What I'd like to do is run a check on the row count. If the results are 0 then the scalar function will return a 1. In the .NET front-end if a 1 is returned then it can query the backup data.

My question is when will the row count get updated in dm_db_partition_stats? Is it immediately or is there some lag involved?

Answer (score 0):

The Dynamic Management Views directly return information about the current internal state of the server, so they are as immediate and real time as it is possible to get. However, the row count from that view is only guaranteed to be approximate, and if there are active transactions in the process of inserting or deleting rows, the count you get may or may not match what you would see if you actually queried the table. So from what you describe it sounds possible that the code that runs subsequently might not find what it was expecting.